# How can I set the NumericUpDown Control to Infinity?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to set the `max` value in the Winforms [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) control to `infinity`. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't edit, but original question was how to set the maximum value of the NumericUpDown control to infinity not the value

Comment: I guarantee that after the max value is set to infinity, someone will want infinity + 1. :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824664/c-is-there-a-way-to-make-the-maximum-value-of-a-numericupdown-control-unlimited ?

Comment: Can you set `Maximum = 8`, and then set the `MaximumOrientation = Vertical`? lol

Answer (score 46):

Don't think you can, but could do:

```
nmrUpDown.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
```

Which sets maximum allowed value to 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335

Comment: Yep, that's the only way, considering (a) the NumericUpDown control value is designed to be always constrained between two values, and (b) the values are of type Decimal which doesn't support infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Setting any object's **maximum to infinty** is **impossible**.

But you can set it to the max value of your computer's capability.

If you want it the largest amount, this should work (depending on your computer's capability again):

```
nud.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
```

> You should get the maximum **79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335** (that is a very big number!) for your `NumericUpDown` if you carefully read my answer and tried my sample.
>
> If you're computer can't handle this, try replacing `decimal.MaxValue` with `long.MaxValue` (Integer 64-bit), or `int.MaxValue` (Normal Integer).

Just replace  `nud` with your actual `NumericUpDown` object name.

Regards,

Me

Comment: How is this different from the [JDunkerley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432495/4934172) which was posted 9 years ago?

Comment: `long.MaxValue`, `int.MaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to create your own user control that mimics the behaviour of a numeric up down. Simply use a TextBox and a vertical scroll bar (VScrollBar) and do some validation.

As your data type you could use a double, that would also format as `"+/-Infinity"` if the value exceeds the range.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Sine](http://www.codeplex.com/sine) on codeplex.com  you can do something like this:

```
BigNum x = 100;
BigNum xPow100 = x.Pow( 100 );
Console.WriteLine("100^100 == " + xPow100.ToString() );
```

But it's still cannot be infinity.  The size of your RAM is your limitation.